# i have string that i want to slice and want to get rest of string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react also i have string that looks like this

```
<h2>h2 one</h2> <p>Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
<h2>h2 two</h2> fames ac turpis. Ridiculus mus mauris 
vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.
```

so you can see h2 tag also p tags 
i want to only get h2 tags 
which is h2 one , h2 two , two sting

i've try tried splice using indexOf

```
  const res = markDownString?.indexOf('h2');
  const res1 = markDownString?.indexOf('</h2');
  const newMarkDownString = markDownString?.slice(1078, 1093); // which is first h2 tag position
  console.log(newMarkDownString)
```

this way only get first h2 tag how can i get all h2 tag in string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `match` here for a regex option:

```js
var input = "<h2>h2 one</h2> <p>Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada \n<h2>h2 two</h2> fames ac turpis. Ridiculus mus mauris \nvitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.";
var tags = input.match(/(?<=<h2>)(.*?)(?=<\/h2>)/g);
console.log(tags);
```

But note that in general regex should not be relied upon for parsing HTML content.  Instead, use a parsing approach.

Comment: thanks !! it very worked! that's fine i need only string thx man

Answer (score 0):

You can use  DomParse from the browser to get a document object and then u can use document.querySelectorAll

example:

```js
const parser = new window.DOMParser

let stringContainingHTMLSource = "<h2>h2 one</h2> <p>Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada <h2>h2 two</h2> fames ac turpis. Ridiculus mus maurisvitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel."
let doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingHTMLSource, "text/html")

const h2s = doc.querySelectorAll("h2")

console.log(h2s)
h2s.forEach(h2=>console.log(h2.innerText))
```

Comment: Providing a runnable example would make this answer a lot more valuable

Comment: You are right thanks for the tip, i have done that now.